# SmartGWT 3.0 testdata to 3.x?

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

In SmartGWT **3.0**, setting testdata had a `DataClass[]` parameter. An example would be this:

```
public void loadUsers(List<User> params) {
    this.users = new HashMap<String, User>();

    UserDC[] items = new UserDC[params.size()];

    int i = 0;
    for(User item : params) {
        users.put(item.getUsername(), item);
        items[i] = new UserDC(item);
        i++;
    }
    setTestData(items);
}
```

How do I do this in SmartGWT **3.1**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **SmartGWT 3.1**, the DataClass[] parameter was replaced by a Record… parameter. The way I fixed this is by converting each DataClass object to a Javascript Object and collecting them in a Record Array. Like this:

```
public void loadUsers(List<User> params) {
        this.users = new HashMap<String, User>();

        Record[] items = new Record[params.size()];

        int i = 0;
        for(User item : params) {
            users.put(item.getUsername(), item);
            items[i] = new Record(new UserDC(item).getJsObj());
            i++;
        }


        setTestData(items);

    }
```